# save data inside an array from a loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I need to save data in array from a loop so I can insert into database.

This is the code:

```
$dataset = array();
 for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['num_cart_items']; $i++) {
 $dataset[item_name] = $_POST['item_name' + $i];
$dataset[item_number] =$_POST['item_number' + $i];
 $dataset[mc_gross] =$_POST['mc_gross_' + $i];
}
```

and I don't know if it's right could use like this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexion_temporal,"INSERT INTO transacciones (item_name, item_number, payment_status ,mc_gross) VALUES ('$dataset[item_name]', '$dataset[item_number]','$payment_status','$dataset[mc_gross]')");
```

So if I bought 2 items I can show like this:

items: racket,spoon

item numbers: d67,t87

price: 4500,3789

and so use when I bought only 1 item.

Comment: I think when looping you are overriding the the previous values you have inserted in the array. You need to use a multidimensional array for $dataset.

Comment: dataset is empty i will only use for those 3 elements

Comment: Yes but if you have multiple items only the last item will be saved as the others will be overridden.

Comment: i only acept 7 items per cart

Comment: you should be getting errors .use `'` or `" ` for keys like `$dataset['item_name'].` and create new index for each iteration then assign the values.

Comment: you can use multidimensional array of each 3 element (like :  $dataset[item_name][] )and implode after foreach and set those values in insert query..

Comment: `$_POST['item_name' + $i] ==`? `$_POST['item_name1' ]` or `$_POST['item_name']+1` remember `$_POST['item_name' + $i]` means `$_POST[1]` .use dot(.) instead of + if it means `$_POST['item_name1']`

Answer (score 0):

Use a multidimensional array to save your items as not to override the values when looping.

```
 $dataset = array();
     for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['num_cart_items']; $i++) {
     $dataset[$i]['item_name'] = $_POST['item_name' + $i];
    $dataset[$i]['item_number'] =$_POST['item_number' + $i];
     $dataset[$i]['mc_gross'] =$_POST['mc_gross_' + $i];
    }
```

And when inserting into SQL use a foreach loop around the statement.

Something similar to this:

```
foreach($dataset as $item){
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexion_temporal,"INSERT INTO transacciones (item_name, item_number, payment_status ,mc_gross) VALUES (".$item['item_name'].", ".$item['item_number'].",".$payment_status.",".$item['mc_gross'].")");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
$keys = array_keys($dataset);

$str = ''.
foreach($dataset as $k => $v){
$str .= '\''.$v.'\'';
}
$presql = '"INSERT INTO transacciones ('.implode(',',$keys).')VALUES('.$str.')';

$sql = mysqli_query($presql);
```

Comment: add dummy payment_status key and value to dataset, update in later in database ... i suppose status might be changing over time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataset = '';
 for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['num_cart_items']; $i++) {
   $dataset .= "('" . $_POST['item_name'] . "',";
   $dataset .= "'" . $_POST['item_number'] . "',";
   $dataset .= "'" . $payment_status . "',"; // not sure where this one is coming from
   $dataset .= "'" . $_POST['mc_gross_'] . "')";
   if ($i != $_POST['num_cart_items']) $dataset .= ',';
}

$sql = mysqli_query($conexion_temporal,"INSERT INTO transacciones (item_name, item_number, payment_status ,mc_gross) VALUES $dataset");
```

If numbers are not stored as text you should remove the quotes around that value.

Comment: you have to be a little more specific otherwise people can not help you. use `echo $dataset;` after the `}` of the `for`-loop. What does it display?

Answer (score 0):

User multidimensional in foreach, like :

```
$dataset = array();
 for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['num_cart_items']; $i++) {
 $dataset['item_name'][] = $_POST['item_name_'.$i];
$dataset['item_number'][] =$_POST['item_number_'.$i];
 $dataset['mc_gross'][] =$_POST['mc_gross_'.$i];
}
```

Implode with "," to each element:

```
$item_name = implode(",",$dataset['item_name']);
$item_number = implode(",",$dataset['item_number']);
$mc_gross = implode(",",$dataset['mc_gross']);
```

Use that implode string in insert query like :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexion_temporal,"INSERT INTO transacciones (item_name, item_number, payment_status ,mc_gross) VALUES ('$item_name', '$item_number','$payment_status','$mc_gross')");
```

NOTE : keep in mind the concept describe by  `Shaiful Islam` in comment

Comment: echo value of $_POST['item_name' + $i], what you getting?

Comment: what is field name? it is like item_name1,item_name2.. ??

Comment: item_name ,item_numer and mc_gross

Comment: instead of $_POST['item_name' + $i] you have to write like $_POST['item_name'.$i] if your form input name is like item_name1,item_name2..

Comment: its aypal and it send items like item_name_1,item_name_2 ,etc